# why django not able to pic or get uploaded images from database?

Tags: django, django-views, django-media

What i want is that when user fills up the registration form and upload his pic , in want that pic to be show on index.html page but its not showing up there so please help me guys

all the images are been stored in `money/prifile_images` folder

this is my index.html code

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Bank{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'money/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body id="bg" style="background-image: url('{% static "money/bg.jpg"%}')"; style="background-image: url('{% static "money/bg.jpg"%}')";>
    <div class="indexdiv">
        <h1 class="indextitle">Gautam Bank</h1>
        <div class="indexsign">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                Signed in as <strong>{{ user.username }}</strong>.
            {% else %}
                Not signed in.
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'balance' %}">Balance</a>
            </li>
            
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'send' %}">Send Money</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link history-link" href="{% url 'history' %}">Transaction History</a>
                </li>
                
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'loan' %}">Apply for Loan</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Logout</a>
                </li>
            
        </ul>
        
        <hr>
       
        </div>
         <div class="indeximg">
             {% if user_profile and user_profile.image %}
               <img height="138" width="152" src="{{ user_profile.image.url }}" alt="User Profile Image">
             {% else %}
               <img height="138" width="152" src="{% static 'money/pic.jpg' %}" alt="Default Image">
             {% endif %}
       </div>
        
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from .models import User,Transaction,BankAccount, UserProfile
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpRequest, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import JsonResponse
from decimal import Decimal


@login_required
def index(request):
    # Fetch the user profile
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request, "money/index.html", {"user": request.user,"user_profile": user_profile})


def balance(request):
    return render(request,"money/balance.html")

def send(request):
    return render(request,"money/sendmoney.html")

def history(request):
    return render(request,"money/history.html")

def loan(request):
    return render(request,"money/loan.html")




def send_money_api(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        amount = request.POST.get("amount")
        to_whom_mcode = request.POST.get("towhom")
        


        recieveruser= User.objects.get(userprofile__mcode = to_whom_mcode)

        recieveracc=BankAccount.objects.get(user=recieveruser)
        try:
            senderacc = BankAccount.objects.get(user=request.user) 

            # Check if sender is trying to send money to themselves
            if senderacc.user == recieveruser:
                return JsonResponse({"success": False, "message": "Invalid recipient MCODE."})

          

            # Convert amount to Decimal before performing subtraction
            amount_decimal = Decimal(amount)

            if senderacc.balance >= amount_decimal > 0:

                senderacc.balance -= amount_decimal
                recieveracc.balance += amount_decimal

                senderacc.save()
                recieveracc.save()

                # Create a single Transaction record for the transaction
                Transaction.objects.create(sender=request.user, receiver=recieveruser, amount=float(amount))

                return JsonResponse({"success" : True})
            else:
                return JsonResponse({"success": False, "message": "Insufficient balance."})
        except (User.DoesNotExist, BankAccount.DoesNotExist):
            return JsonResponse({"success": False, "message": "Invalid recipient mcode."})
     
    return JsonResponse({"success": False, "message": "Invalid request method."})   



def history(request):
    # Retrieve the user's sent and received transactions
    # Get transactions where the user is either the sender or the receiver
    transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(sender=request.user) | Transaction.objects.filter(receiver=request.user)

    return render(request, 'money/history.html', {'transactions': transactions})


def login_in(request):
    if request.method =="POST":

     name = request.POST['name']
     password = request.POST['password']

     user = authenticate(request,username=name, password=password)

     if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
     else:
        return render(request,"money/login.html",{
           "message":"Invalid Name or Password"
        })
     
    else:
       return render(request, "money/login.html")
    


def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.FILES)  # Add this line to print request.FILES
        name = request.POST['name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        date = request.POST['date']
        mobile = request.POST['mobile']
        address = request.POST['address']
        tcode = request.POST['tcode']
        
        # Use request.FILES for file uploads (like images)
        image = request.FILES['image']
        if 'image' in request.FILES:
            image = request.FILES['image']
        else:
            return render(request, "money/register.html", {
                "message": "Please select an image."
            })
       
        password = request.POST['password']
        cpassword = request.POST['cpassword']
        
        # Check if passwords match
        if password != cpassword:
            return render(request, "money/register.html", {
                "message": "Password must match."
            })
        

         
      
        try:
            # Create a user instance
            user = User.objects.create_user(name, email, password)
            user.save()

            # Authenticate the user
            auth_user = authenticate(request, username=name, password=password)

            # Log in the user
            login(request, auth_user)

            # Create a BankAccount instance for the user
            bank_account = BankAccount(user=request.user, balance=100.00)
            bank_account.save()

            # Create a user profile instance
            profile = UserProfile(
                user=request.user,  # Associate with the authenticated user
                date_of_birth=date,
                mobile_number=mobile,
                address=address,
                mcode=tcode,
                image=image,
            )
            profile.save()

            # Redirect to the index page
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        except IntegrityError:
            # Handle duplicate user creation
            return render(request, "money/register.html", {
                "message": "User with this email already exists."
            })
        except ValidationError:
            return render(request, "money/register.html", {
                "message": "Invalid data submitted."
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "money/register.html")
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.login_in,name="login"),
    path("register",views.register,name="register"),
    path("index", views.index,name="index"),
    path("history",views.history, name="history"),
    path("loan",views.loan,name="loan"),
    path("balance",views.balance,name="balance"),
    path("send", views.send, name="send"),
    path('send_money_api/', views.send_money_api, name='send_money_api'),
    path('history/', views.history, name='transaction_history'),
]

# Serve uploaded media files during development
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Show settings.py part related to media files storage configuration. And elaborate whether DEBUG = True or False.

Comment: thanks bro its working now, i was looking for results in balance.html , history.html and other, i logged out and logged in again and the image was showing but when i clicked on balance and other links didn't show, and that's because i the image code was only written in def index not in other def so now i write the code in all defs and now its showing in all pages thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 @login_required
def index(request):
    # Fetch the user profile
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request, "money/index.html", {"user": request.user,"user_profile": user_profile})


def balance(request):
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request,"money/balance.html", { "user": request.user,"user_profile": user_profile })

def send(request):
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request,"money/sendmoney.html", { "user": request.user,"user_profile": user_profile })

def history(request):
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request,"money/history.html", { "user": request.user,"user_profile": user_profile })

def loan(request):
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request,"money/loan.html", { "user": request.user,"user_profile": user_profile })
```

**read my comment also**